# Sapper - add .mode-dark to document during SSR

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, svelte, sapper

Given basic _layout.svelte component

```
<script context="module">
  import { darkMode } from "../store";
  import { isLoading, waitLocale } from 'svelte-i18n';

  export async function preload(page) {
    darkMode.set(getCookie("isDark") || window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches);
    return waitLocale();
  }
</script>
```

I have two questions:

1. why preload in layout doesn't run even if I just add the only console.log inside
2. how to add class '.mode-dark' to the `document` on the server-side? document is undefined

Comment: I don't see `console.log` in your code. Are you saying you added it in `preload` previously and didn't see any output?

Comment: @ConnorLow yes, in my app preload in the layout is dead in dev env, not sure how to fix that.